# Question about analytic function that maps unit disc into itself

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function that maps the open unit disc into itself, $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = 0$, $|f''(0)| = 2$. Show $f(z) = cz^2$ for some $|c|=1$.

Comment: Have you any idea how to attack it?

Comment: The problem looks vaguely related to Schwarz's lemma, but I can't see how to incorporate the information about the second derivative of $f$.

Comment: It is related. Do you recall the proof of the Schwarz lemma? If so, try to think how that could be modified for the present case.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. Thank you!